# nivo-caption same position resize window

Tags: css, wordpress, nivo-slider

I've installed the nivo-slider for a wordpress site. This works very well.
I also have a nivo-caption (text-overlay the slider images). This text-bar have to be on the same position in the slider regarless what screen resolution is used. 
I can't figure it out how to do so. What i'm trying, the text-bar in the slider always resize with the screen resolution.

The site is: http://vanschendel.com/wordpress

Css code nivo-slider:
`
     /* 
      * jQuery Nivo Slider v3.1
      * http://nivo.dev7studios.com
      *
      * Copyright 2012, Dev7studios
      * Free to use and abuse under the MIT license.
      * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
      */

```
 /* The Nivo Slider styles */
  .nivoSlider {
     position:relative;
     width:100%;
     height:auto;
     overflow: hidden;
  }
  .nivoSlider img {
     position:absolute;
     top:0px;
     left:0px;
     max-width: none;
  }
  .nivo-main-image {
     display: block !important;
     position: relative !important; 
     width: 100% !important;
  }

  /* If an image is wrapped in a link */
  .nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink {
     position:absolute;
     top:0px;
     left:0px;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     border:0;
     padding:0;
     margin:0;
     z-index:6;
     display:none;
 }
 /* The slices and boxes in the Slider */
  .nivo-slice {
     display:block;
     position:absolute;
     z-index:5;
     height:100%;
     top:0;
 }
  .nivo-box {
     display:block;
     position:absolute;
     z-index:5;
     overflow:hidden;
 }
 .nivo-box img { display:block; }

 /* Caption styles */
 .nivo-caption {
     position:absolute;
     /*left:0px;*/
     /*left:40px;*/
     margin:0 auto 0 680px;
     bottom:0px;
     background:#eaecee;
     color:#373737;
     /*width:100%;*/
     width:5000px;
     height:35%;
     z-index:8;
     padding: 5px 10px;
     opacity: 0.9;
     overflow: hidden;
     display: none;
     -moz-opacity: 0.8;
     filter:alpha(opacity=8);
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
     box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
 }
```

Comment: Does nobody has an idea?

Comment: Got is wordking (finally) by giving the .nivo-caption:{left:50%, margin-left:-270px}